# Golang why the result is not equal 1000?

Tags: go

I have the next code

```
func main() {
    var counter int
    m := &sync.Mutex{}


    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go func(m *sync.Mutex) {
            m.Lock()
            counter++
            m.Unlock()
        }(m)
    }

    fmt.Println(counter)
}
```

But I can't understand why the counter is not equal 1000? I am using mutex for locking and I am waiting for the program will wait unlock

Comment: Your code is racy: Your read of counter in fmt.Println(counter) is not guarded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're printing the result before all the goroutines complete. Use a [`WaitGroup`](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup) to wait for them:

```
func main() {
    var counter int
    m := &sync.Mutex{}
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1000)
    for i := 0; i < 1000; i++ {
        go func(m *sync.Mutex) {    
            m.Lock()
            counter++
            m.Unlock()
            wg.Done()
        }(m)
    }

    wg.Wait()
    fmt.Println(counter)
}
```

Comment: Thanks. Next question can be strange but Is it possible to emulate WaitGroup using only golang channels? Without sync package?

Comment: @Viktor make each goroutine write something to the same channel in the end, then in the main routine read from that channel 1000 times in a loop. Not worth the effort, `WaitGroup` is implemented [way more efficiently](https://golang.org/src/sync/waitgroup.go).

Comment: @Viktor, if you want to use channel, for me, you can use buffered channel with only 1 size to lock for reading and writing